# What are some careers in theoretical computer science that do not require a PhD?

Tags: soft-question, career

I am an undergraduate, and have recently come to terms with the fact that I may not have the intellect to do research in theoretical computer science, or be able to be admitted into and complete a PhD program.  However, I would still like to be involved with theoretical computer science as I find it very interesting.  So far, the only careers in theoretical computer science that do not require a PhD that I can think of would be being a secretary or administrative assistant for the theory group in some university.  Are there any others?

Comment: Popular science writer? You could write the next Godel Escher Bach. But I'd advise you not to sell yourself short too soon -- most scientists have at some point doubted whether they had what it took to succeed in their field, before they discovered that they did.

Comment: Another idea is to work for an academic publisher, though the consensus is that this industry is about to go through radical change.  But what industry isn't these days?  Also, I agree with @Aaron about not selling yourself short too early.

Comment: Perhaps you are very lucid about your own abilities. On the other hand, here in France, I can't think of anybody that knew they were going to do a PhD while an undergraduate. When you are an undergraduate, a PhD, and the amount of "imagination" you assume you will require is daunting---in part because most PhD's you've heard about at that point are geniuses.

Comment: Discouragement is common, at all stages. Take a look [at this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/2219/66). Don't give up!

Comment: Contrary to what everybody else is saying, I would suggest you to consider a more relaxed approach toward your future employment. Why does it have to do anything with **theoretical** computer science? Perhaps there are other things you would enjoy? Do you really think you'll enjoy being a secretary? Plus, the job market in TCS-related jobs (or even TCS) is quite small. Why limit yourself?

Comment: Whether or not you try for a PhD is a personal decision only you can make.  But I have some perspective, as a guy in his 40s working on a CS PhD.  First:  Having a PhD is not everything, and you can live a long and happy life without one.  I wanted to get one right out of undergrad and for various reasons, didn't.  I had (and have!) a great career in industry.  Second:  If and when you get accepted to a program, that sense that you're not smart enough won't magically go away.  At least, it hasn't for me.  It haunts most (maybe all) of us.

Comment: @Novak: I think having that feeling is largely independent of how good you actually are.

Comment: @Yuval: I've taken quite a few theory classes, and those are the ones I've enjoyed the most.  On the other hand, I've had a few internships in industry that I did not enjoy.  Although being a secretary might not be the best job, it would be nice in that I would get to interact with those that do theory on a regular basis and maybe I could talk about their research.  If no other jobs in theory exist that is fine, I can do something else, but I would like to see what is out there.

Comment: @user10240: You're painting a very romantic picture, but the stark reality is that most people work at a job they are at best indifferent about. As a secretary in a CS department, don't expect to "talk theory" with the researchers; life is not a Hollywood movie! Instead you'll spend your time preparing and collating forms. I suggest you wait a while until this dream dissolves, and a more practical life plan replaces it.

Comment: some in academia & even elsewhere refer to the PhD as a "union card" which tells you something. also note how many people say they have an ABD... "all but dissertation".... another option is to stay a graduate student & maybe a teaching assistant for an indefinite period of time, if youre not insistent about high pay.... as they say sometimes "dont quit your day job".... do it as a hobby. there are many ways to cultivate it in cyberspace eg online university courses (maybe even with prof office/chat hrs), papers, forums, emails, chat, etc

Answer (score 9):

I work at a national lab and in a directorate that employs many theoretical computer scientists, of which some do not have PhDs.

I think that what would differentiate or establish you would be a quality of your work.
If you are a talented theoretician, strong at algorithms and you can/have been publishing your work in reputable theoretical computer science journals then I do not see why place like national lab would not hire you.

PhD is a testimony of ones ability to pursue relevant and significant research on his or her own.

Comment: If you are a talented theoretician who is strong at algorithms then it sounds like you're material for a PhD programme. On the other hand, if you're not in a PhD programme and you're not yet employed by a research institution, you're presumably holding down a full-time job that doesn't involve CS research. Where are you going to find the time to do research and publish it in high-quality journals? Finally, most PhD research these days is highly collaborative: it's not at all about working on your own.